# WebJob Using Entity Framework Core: Accessing Site Configuration Information

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, azure-webjobs

I'm building an ASP.NET Core MVC site which uses an EF Core Sql Server database.

In part of the site I need to add the ability to upload files, which then get processed and applied to the database. I thought I would use WebJobs for this.

What I'm not clear on is how I share the database connection string between my website and the webjob. Is there something analogous to the ConfigureServices() method in the website's Startup.cs which I can use in the webjob's program Main()?

**Program Main**

Per request, here is my current WebJobs code in all its glory:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var config = new JobHostConfiguration();

    if( config.IsDevelopment )
    {
        config.UseDevelopmentSettings();
        config.DashboardConnectionString = "...";
        config.StorageConnectionString = "...";
    }

    JobHost host = new JobHost( config );
    host.RunAndBlock();
}
```

Not at lot there, but I'm just starting :)

Comment: Are you storing your credentials in appsettings.{Environment}.json?

Comment: Yes. But I don't see how to access those from the WebJob executable, which seems to run in its own environment, outside my MVC site.

Comment: can you post your Console App code. There's a way to add a startup class and access the hosting environment variable.

Answer (score 2):

As I know, Azure Web app and WebJob share App setting and connection strings set on Azure portal. So we can define connection string on azure portal, then use ConfigurationManager to get the connection string. I did a small test to verify this for you.

1) Set connection string 'myconnection' with value 'test'
[image]

2) use web job project to output the connection

```html
 public static void ProcessQueueMessage([QueueTrigger("queue")] string message, TextWriter log)
        {
            log.WriteLine(message);
            string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myconnection"].ToString();
            Console.WriteLine("this is my webjob project console write " + connectionString);
        }
```

3) Then I see the result in Azure web job dashboard

[image]

Comment: Thanx, Jambor. How does this approach work in the development environment, where I am setting configuration parameters in appsettings.json?

Comment: You could find  .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true) in your startup.cs. We can load JSON file with an environment specific name and with optional set to true. If we are running in developing mode, it will load appsettings.Development.json, and the existing settings will be overridden by the new one